# How do I abbreviate month to 3 characters?

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, android-calendar, android-date

I am trying to abbreviate month in date time to 3 characters, say if the month is May, it shows May, but if the month is june, it should show Jun, and september should show sep and so on.

I have tried "MMM" but that does not work, it seems to return the full text for month.

```
Calendar mDate = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMM d, yyyy", Locale.US);
mMyStartDate.setText(mDateFormat.format(mDate.getTime()));
```

Any ideas how to go about it? Also, I don't want anything else to change. just month, but have had no luck so far.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have to use a `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`? They are deprecated…

Comment: @deHaar is there anything else I can use? pretty much open to anything

Comment: Yes, I recommend getting familiar with `java.time`, I will post a (very simple) answer soon...

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem on non-android environment: https://ideone.com/FWz4Bs

Comment: I hope there is no difference between java and android here...

Comment: There shouldn't be. Not sure why it's not picking up simpledateformat. Maybe my editor is caching the value

Comment: Which class do you really import as `SimpleDateFormat`, from `java.text`-package or from `android.icu.text`? Maybe they have different i18n-resources on your device.

Comment: i use the android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat "https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat" probably thats causing the discrepancy but either way since SimpleDateFormat is deprecated I am more than happy using java.time class with DateTimeFormatter.

Comment: @deharr SimpleDateFormat and Calendar are not deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `java.time` package for this. There is a class `DateTimeFormatter` which you can utilize to format temporal objects, like `LocalDateTime`, `LocalDate` and `LocalTime`.

This is a very simple example for formatting a date:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd yyyy");
    System.out.println(today.format(dtf));
}
```

The output (in my locale) is `Mai 07 2019`.

Have a look at the built-in formats [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Comment: Thanks for this, this seems to work! will update to DateTimeFormatter throughout my codebase. thanks!

Comment: any idea about this one? : are you into android coding? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56159855/how-do-i-make-my-button-which-is-fixed-at-the-bottom-of-a-layout-scroll-once-th?noredirect=1#com

Answer (score 0):

you can do: `LocalDate myDate = LocalDate.now();` then you can format it using date formatter`myDate.format(new DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd yyyy"))`